# GetX ecosystem help: Can I replace a simple Flutter class with a GetxController?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

### Introduction:

---

I am new to Flutter and Android Application development and want to step into getX ecosystem. I have heard that a GetxController will perform better in comparison with a simple dart class, but have some basic doubts.

**The doubts:**

1. Can I replace a normal class with a GetxController?
2. What are the advantages I will get for doing so?

### Here's what I tried:

---

Here's a normal class:

```
class WeatherModel {
  
  String getWeatherIcon(int condition) {
    if (condition < 300) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 400) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 600) {
      return '☔️';
    } else if (condition < 700) {
      return '☃️';
    } else if (condition < 800) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition == 800) {
      return '☀️';
    } else if (condition <= 804) {
      return '☁️';
    } else {
      return '‍';
    }
  }

  String getMessage(int temp) {
    if (temp > 25) {
      return 'It\'s  time';
    } else if (temp > 20) {
      return 'Time for shorts and ';
    } else if (temp < 10) {
      return 'You\'ll need  and ';
    } else {
      return 'Bring a  just in case';
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to convert this to a GetxController:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class WeatherModel extends GetxController {
  
  String getWeatherIcon(int condition) {
    if (condition < 300) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 400) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 600) {
      return '☔️';
    } else if (condition < 700) {
      return '☃️';
    } else if (condition < 800) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition == 800) {
      return '☀️';
    } else if (condition <= 804) {
      return '☁️';
    } else {
      return '‍';
    }
  }

  String getMessage(int temp) {
    if (temp > 25) {
      return 'It\'s  time';
    } else if (temp > 20) {
      return 'Time for shorts and ';
    } else if (temp < 10) {
      return 'You\'ll need  and ';
    } else {
      return 'Bring a  just in case';
    }
  }
}
```

So, am I doing it right? Give me some tips for doing this correctly, and finally what are the advantages I get after converting?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What you prefer over getx?

Comment: **ANYTHING**.  Even hand-rolled InheritedWidget and ChangeNotifiers would be better.  My go-to is Riverpod, the successor to Provider from the same author.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I will switch to Riverpod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetxController**

Controllers are classes where all our business logic goes. All the variables and methods are placed here and can be accessed from the `view`. While we can just create a simple class for this purpose, `GetX` provides a class called `GetxController` which extends `DisposableInterface`.

This means that our controller will get deleted from memory as soon as the widgets using it are removed from the navigation stack. We don’t have to manually dispose anything and the memory consumption is reduced, resulting in high performance.

`GetxController` comes with `onInit()` and `onClose()` methods which essentially replace the `initState()` and `dispose()` methods of the `StatefulWidget`. This allows us to completely avoid using `StatefulWidget` and write highly organized code.